# Id cannot be found from check function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small issue with my code in javascript and HTML. The problem is that the function `document.getElementById('id').checked` can't find (I guess) the 'id' because I print this and isn't static. As the `total` variable is not incremented. I added an example. Also, I am new to javascript.

```
if(case1){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<p style='color:red'>What is your genre?</p>"+
        "<input type='radio' id='q1' name='quest1' value='quest1.1' >"+
        "<label for='quest1.1'>Male</label><br>"+
        "<input type='radio' id='q2' name='quest1' value='quest1.2' >"+
        "<label for='quest1.2'>Female</label><br>"+";

 if(document.getElementById('q1').checked){       /*If 'Male' is checked*/
    total++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the HTML you injected is not checked by default, hence the 'if' loop did not run. If you add "checked" to your HTML, it will work.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<input type='radio' id='q1' name='quest1' value='male' checked>"+
```

This get the function to fire, but without knowing your use case, we won't know whether this is what you want. If you want the function to fire only when you check the box, you need to add an onChange eventListener to fire the function.

Comment: No i want to be unchecked the radios inputs when they will be printed.Also i want to to "print" the radios because i have other cases with others radios and questions(text).The radios are there for answers in some questions that i have print above the radios.

Comment: If that’s the case you definitely need to wrap the second if statement inside a function so that it fires if your radios are clicked. As it is the code only run once so any further actions won’t trigger it any more. As mentioned by TJ, we could help you better if you can give us a minimal reproducible example